# Login failed when again hashing password for reset password using crypto npm in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cryptography

I am making api for `reset the password`. When I first signup the user with hashing `password` using `crypto.pbkdf2Sync` firstly I generate salt and then used that salt for hashing the `password` and save that salt and hashed password in a database.

API for `reset password`

```
export function newPassword(req,res) {
  if (req.body.newpassword.length < 1)
    return res.status(400).json({message: "Please Enter a new password"});
  jwt.verify(req.token, TOKEN_SECRET, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    else {
      User.findOne({_id : data._id}).exec()
        .then(user =>{
          console.log(user);
          var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(req.body.newpassword,user.salt,10000,64,'sha1').toString('base64');
          console.log(key);

          User.update({_id: data._id}, {$set: {password: key}})
            .then(data => {
              res.json(data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.status(400).json(err);
            });
          }
        )
        .catch(err =>{
          res.status(400).json(err);
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Here login works successfully.

When i fetch that saved `salt` and use that salt for again hashing the `password` during the reset of `password`.

```
crypto.pbkdf2Sync(newpassword,user.salt,defaultIterations,defaultKeyLength,'sha1')
```

It shows message login failed. //this is not error . this is message which i set if auth failed.

Note - I am not updating the `salt` again in a database.

I wanted to know that why it show login failed when first time before it show successfully

Comment: "It show login failed." Can you show us what triggers your website to say that? What errors produce this?

Comment: @Luca it is not an error .it is message which i set in case of auth failed.

Comment: Well, then what does actually fail here? Creating the Hash?

Comment: i wanted to know that why it shows login failed when first time loged in successfully

Comment: Could you please add all the code that gets called while you "reset the password"? That would help in trying to figure out why it shows that

Comment: @Luca i have added reset password code